# Cpp Pantheios Log Library, Debug Assertion Failed Error

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, logging, pantheios

I have a cpp project, a cpp cli project and a c# win forms project. 
I use pantheios log library in my cpp native project. When i try to write log, i take this error :

[image: Log Error]

Here is my codes :

Log.hpp

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_LOG_HPP
#define INCLUDE_LOG_HPP


#define PANTHEIOS_NO_INCLUDE_OS_AND_3PTYLIB_STRING_ACCESS // Faster compilation

/* Pantheios Header Files */
#include <pantheios/pantheios.hpp>            // Pantheios C++ main header
#include <pantheios/inserters/args.hpp>       // for pantheios::args

#include <pantheios/backends/bec.file.h>      // be.file header

#include "Include/utility.hpp"
/* Standard C/C++ Header Files */
#include <exception>                          // for std::exception
#include <new>                                // for std::bad_alloc
#include <string>                             // for std::string
#include <stdlib.h>           
#include <sstream>

#define PSTR(x)         PANTHEIOS_LITERAL_STRING(x)


namespace Mtx
{
    namespace log
    {
        class MTXMANAGER Logger
        {
        public:
            void WriteLogIn(const std::string & log_text);
            Logger();
            ~Logger();
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

Log.cpp

```
#include "Log.hpp"
namespace Mtx
{
    namespace log
    {
        PANTHEIOS_EXTERN_C const PAN_CHAR_T PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY[] = PANTHEIOS_LITERAL_STRING("mtx");//
        Logger::Logger()
        {
            char path[MAX_PATH];
            GetModuleFileName( NULL, path, MAX_PATH );

            std::string::size_type pos = std::string( path ).find_last_of( "\\" );
            strcpy(path,std::string( path ).substr( 0, pos).c_str());
            std::strcat (path,"\\mtx-%D__.log");
            /////

            pantheios_be_file_setFilePath(PSTR(path), PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE, PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_SHARE_ON_WINDOWS, PANTHEIOS_BEID_ALL);

        }

        Logger::~Logger()
        {

        }

        void Logger::WriteLogIn(const std::string & log_text)
        {
            pantheios::log_INFORMATIONAL(PSTR("   [1]   "),PSTR(log_text));
        }  

    }
}
```

I take the error at this line :

```
pantheios::log_INFORMATIONAL(PSTR("   [1]   "),PSTR(log_text));
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I don't have a direct answer for you, but comparing what I have in my solution (which is similar in many aspects with your setup - .NET DLL calling a C++-native DLL, which has Pantheios-logging), here is what I have:

- I have a project LOG, which has an InitInstance() and ExitInstance() (and ctors for the CWinApp-derived class - CLogApp)
- CLogApp ctor/dtor are empty
- The code in InitInstance() and ExitInstance():

  ```
  BOOL CLogApp::InitInstance()
  {
      CWinApp::InitInstance();

      int panres =  pantheios::pantheios_init();

      if( panres < 0 )
      {
          OutputDebugStringA("Could not initialise the Pantheios logging libraries!\n");
          util::onBailOut(pantheios::emergency, "Failed to initialise the Pantheios libraries", PANTHEIOS_FE_PROCESS_IDENTITY, /*pantheios::*/pantheios_getInitCodeString(panres));

         return FALSE;
       }
       else
       {
      pantheios_be_file_setFilePath(CErrorHandler::getLogPath().c_str(), PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE, PANTHEIOS_BE_FILE_F_TRUNCATE, PANTHEIOS_BEID_LOCAL);

      PANTHEIOS_TRACE_NOTICE("STARTING LOGGING");
       }

       return TRUE;
   }

   int CLogApp::ExitInstance()
   {
       PANTHEIOS_TRACE_NOTICE("STOPPING LOGGING");
       pantheios_uninit();
       return 0;
   }
  ```

I am not sure if this will help, but this code has been working for me for many years now.